# Run Hyper-V on Windows Server 2008 R2 in VirtualBox VM?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

Has anyone been able to get Hyper-V to run on Windows Server 2008 R2 in a VM?

Host is Windows 7 Professional 64
VirtualBox is version 4.0.12
Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise is the checked build version

I followed these instructions for setup:
http://www.sysprobs.com/install-run-windows-2008-r2-x86-sun-virtualbox

Enable VT-x checkbox is checked; and the host system is enabled for virtualization.

When I try to enable Hyper-V I get the message that my environment doesn't support it.

Purpose is to be able to spin up various components as needed for a small self contained dev environment under Hyper-V that I could archive off to other storage media when done.

I don't necessarily need to run it under VirtualBox, any free VM alternative would work.  I also use VMPlayer and VirtualPC. Or maybe installing Hyper-V directly on the host would be preferable (although the reason I'm running it under Server 2008 is because it already has all the components I'm looking for - AD, CA, IIS)

Answer (score 2):

You can use kvm-linux. It's passing through the virtualisation features.

Answer (score 1):

The processor extensions only get passed from the main host to the virtual machine layer. They do not get passed from virtual machine to an embedded virtual machine.

Comment: So it is not possible to run Hyper-V in a VM?  Thanks

Comment: Not possible if the extensions are required.